# SQL Query to group continuous numbers into different grouping sets

Tags: sql, numbers, grouping, continuous

I've a table Serial with more than a million records. Few of the sample varchar(MAX) of values are given below:

```
SerialNumber
 1
 2
 3
 4 
 7
 8
 9
13
14
15
19
21
```

I wish to group continuous range of values with same group into a sets like this:

```
fromSerial       toSerial     Total
 1                4            4
 7                9            3
13               15           3
19               19           1
21               21           1
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Your problem is performance. The 'conventional' solution is likely to be agonisingly slow on a data set of this size. I think a solution using a couple of variables is the way to go.